# GO_GAE build go-playground error

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I wanna upload [go-playground](https://code.google.com/p/go-playground/) to my own GAE to code with go online. 
Firstly, I use the command `goapp serve` and it returns Can't find package "code.google.com/p/go.tools/godoc. Then, I download it, `go get code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/godoc`;
But then, when I retry `goapp serve` command and it shows this: `gocode/src/code.google.com/p/go.tools/astutil/enclosing.go:435: n.Lparen undefined (type *ast.TypeAssertExpr has no field or method Lparen)`; I try to fix this with go1.1 & go1.2 and it doesn't work. I'm a fresh man with go, can anyone help me with this? thx.

Comment: This sounds like it may be a $GOPATH error. Check the environment variable to make sure you're using the Go 1.2 packages. See http://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/#TypeAssertExpr for the docs, and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-dev/4kkT03xen7Y/gcuDdEJoSGcJ for previous discussion. It looks like the `Lparen` field was only introduced to the stable branch in 1.2 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Godoc requires Go 1.2, but Go App Engine only picks up Go 1.2 from App Engine 1.9.0. You'll either need to wait for that, or upload with `api_version: go1.2beta`.